# Allow Orgin in my API

Tags: angularjs, jersey

I need to put allow origin in my Jersery Project. 
m getting error:-
 access-control-allow-origin-issue-in-angular-2
Where should I need to put.

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getLipid() {
    LipidDAO dao = new LipidDAO();
    List lipid = dao.getLipid();
    String json = new Gson().toJson(lipid);
    return Response.ok().entity(json.toString()).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tack it on as a header after the Response.ok()

```
return Response.ok()
    .entity(json.toString())
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
    .build();
```

Or do it in an implementation of ContainerResponseFilter and register that filter to your application.

Probably don't want to leave it as * unless you want user's browsers from other sites accessing your API though.

Comment: I have Tried it but its not working for me..Anything i have to add (cross allow origin) in angular 2 header part ?